# Update trigger updating all rows in a table

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a trigger I need to write to update a row to 'F' in a table called StudentGrades (which contains student_id, section_id, and grade) to fire when a student's status is changed to 'I' in a different table called student. My problem is I thought it worked, but it'll update all the values to 'F' no matter what the status is updated to and it updates the grades for all the student_id's in the table. Here's my code:

```
create or replace NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER grades_trigger 

AFTER UPDATE ON STUDENT 

FOR EACH ROW 

 

BEGIN 

  UPDATE StudentGRADES 

  SET GRADE = 'F' 

  WHERE :NEW.STATUS= 'I'; 

END ;
```

I can post more if I need to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, that would be

```
create or replace noneditionable trigger grades_trigger
  after update on student
  for each row
begin
  if :new.status= 'I' then                --> is student's status changed to I?
     update studentgrades set             --> yes, it is - so - update another table ...
       grade = 'F'
     where student_id = :new.student_id;  --> but not for ALL students - only for the one for which the trigger had fired
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly where I was stuck because I kept trying different was to add the Status to the Where clause and it would never update correctly. Thank you!